# Appending line with special characters in shell

Tags: bash, sed, special-characters

I want to appends each line of the file as below:

file.txt :

```
adminsrv.tar
```

Output:

```bash
- archive: "packages/images/adminsrv.tar"
```

I tried several method like the one below and ended up with error:

```bash
input=/var/tmp/file.txt  
while read -r line
Do
sed -i 's|$line|" - archive: "packages//images//$line"'
done < $input
```

Comment: `Do` is spelled incorrectly. But why do you use a loop and `sed` at all? A sole `echo -- "- archive: "packages/images/$(</var/tmp/file.txt)"  would be sufficient.

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean by _special characters_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just insert new text before every line using `sed` and there is no need to run a shell loop:

```bash
sed 's~.*~- archive: "packages/images/&"~' "$input"

- archive: "packages/images/adminsrv.tar"
```

This `sed` uses `.*` for search for any text and then it substitutes matched text with replacement text and `&` which is back-reference of the matched text.

Comment: I liked the use of the alternative delimiters :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, if you want to edit in place

```
sed -i'' -Ee 's@^(.*)$@- archive: "packages/images/\1"@' file.txt
```

Check `man sed`.

Comment: the above expression throws another error :sed: -e expression #1, char 43: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: Remove the `'\'` from `\(` and `\)` they are not used with Extended REGEX.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, totally agree, however on macOS without escaping: `sed: 1: "s@^(.*)$@- archive: "pa ...": \1 not defined in the RE`

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano - yes, I'm a bit Mac illiterate. it's been 35 years since I used the square boxes `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin no worries, and it's a macOS bug because `man` claims: "An atom is a regular expression enclosed in `()'" (not escaped).